# How to deliver web push notifications from Amazon SNS?

Tags: javascript, amazon-sns, service-worker

I want to implement push notifications on the web browser. Service workers seem to be excellent for managing push notifications on the browser.

I am stuck at sending the push notifications through publishing to the topic because every browser has its own key to decrypt the payload.

How do I achieve the encryption for all web clients in one go ?

Can anybody shed some light on this ?

Comment: You can have your webbrowser call an intermediate app which is responsible to post notifications to SNS. Also, storing key information at client side is a bad practice